# If the target framework of my packages differs from the application target framework, does it create problems?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

My application is targeting asp.net framework 4.6.1. However my packages target net45. My host only supports version 4.6.1 and 3.5. Will this break anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the app targets the newest version of the .NET framework, it executes in a runtime that is backwards compatible with previous versions of the .NET runtime.

see [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info which frameworks are compatible with v4.6.1.